# Computing $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{b}^{c} dx \frac{x}{(a-x+i \epsilon)^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to compute an integral similiar to a Kramers-Kronig, namely

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{b}^{c} dx \frac{x}{(a-x+i \epsilon)^2}
$$

I tried some ways to calculate it, but ended up with various results, since I'm not sure when to properly take the limit.

I just show the straight forwards way i came up with. It should show most of my problems.

$$ \int_{b}^{c} dx \frac{x}{(a-x+i \epsilon)^2}
= -\int_{a-b+i \epsilon}^{a-c+i \epsilon} d\gamma \frac{a-\gamma+i \epsilon}{\gamma^2} = -\int_{a-b+i \epsilon}^{a-c+i \epsilon} d\gamma \left(\frac{a+i \epsilon}{\gamma^2} - \frac{1}{\gamma} \right) = (a+i \epsilon)\left(\frac{1}{a-c+i \epsilon} - \frac{1}{a-b+i \epsilon}\right) + \log\left(\frac{a-c+i \epsilon}{a-b+i \epsilon}\right) 
$$

Taking the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ that should get:

$$
 \frac{a(c-b)}{(a-c)(a-b)}+\log\left(\left|\frac{a-c}{a-b}\right|\right) + i \pi \Theta\left(-\text{sign}\left(\frac{a-c}{a-b}\right)\right)
$$

Here i pulled out the minus out of the logarithm if a is between b and c.

Comment: Your result is correct if $a$ is not between $b$ and $c$. If $a$ is between $b$ and $c$, then the result is correct either if $b < c$ and $\epsilon$ approaches zero from above or if $b > c$ and $\epsilon$ approaches zero from below. Then the imaginary part of $(a - c + i \epsilon)/(a - b + i \epsilon)$ approaches zero from above. The real part approaches a negative value if $a$ is between $b$ and $c$. The conversion from $\ln \gamma_2 - \ln \gamma_1$ to $\ln(\gamma_2/\gamma_1)$ is justified because $[\gamma_1, \gamma_2]$ doesn't cross the branch cut of the logarithm.